# Generic model to call a stored procedure .net core

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ListaUnidadAlumnos]
    @MateriaId INT,
    @UnidadId INT,
    @Columnas AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = Null,
    @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = Null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        @Columnas = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(char(10), L.Fecha, 120)) 
                           FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(A.Fecha)
                                 FROM Asistencias A
                                 INNER JOIN AspNetUsers U ON A.AlumnoId = U.Id
                                 INNER JOIN Unidades UN ON UN.UnidadId = A.UnidadId
                                 INNER JOIN Materias M ON UN.MateriaId = M.MateriaId
                                 WHERE UN.MateriaId = @MateriaId
                                   AND UN.UnidadId = @UnidadId) L
                           GROUP BY L.Fecha
                           ORDER BY L.Fecha asc
                           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

    SET @Query = 'SELECT AlumnoId, ' + @Columnas + ' from 
         (
            SELECT A.AlumnoId, A.Fecha, A.Valor
            FROM Asistencias A
            INNER JOIN AspNetUsers U ON A.AlumnoId = U.Id
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(Valor)
            for Fecha in (' + @Columnas + ')
        ) p '

    EXECUTE(@query)
```

This stored procedure returns:

[image: Result of stored procedure]

The dates are dynamic, depending on the assistance of the class

I am not using entity framework, I execute the procedures in the following way

```
public async Task ObtenerListaMateria(int materiaId)
{
    var pMateriaId = new SqlParameter("@MateriaId", materiaId);

    ListaAlumnosIdMateria = await _context.ListaAlumnosIdMateria
            .FromSql("EXEC ObtenerListaAlumnosIdMateria @MateriaId", pMateriaId)
            .ToListAsync();

    ViewData["NumeroAlumnos"] = ListaAlumnosIdMateria.Count();
    ViewData["Contador"] = 0;
}
```

If I execute the procedures in this way, first I have to create the model with the data that they see in the procedure

My question is, how do you call the procedure if the query will always give me a different number of dates, can I create a generic model?

Comment: From a database perspective, this "crosstab" approach is a bad idea. If you want to present data in columns like that, do it in the _presentation_ layer. Is there any way you can use a data structure that has dates in a single column? Again I must stress it's fundamentally a bad idea.

Comment: After trying, I ended up doing it in the presentation layer. I obtained the dates with a query and the contents of the table with another and at the end making use of the tables, I can accommodate them, thanks Bro

Comment: Based on your comment it seems like one of the purposes of the query was to always show every required date regardless of whether data exists in that date. This is easily achieved using an outer join. If you give some background and explain what you're really trying to do rather than just the solution, often there is a better way